# Error: socket hang up when write response in SpringWeb HandlerInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When the URL of the network request matches some prefix, I hope to use the information of this request to assemble a new http request to request other services, get the return result and write it to the current HttpServletResponse, and then return it to the front end. But when I do, mail carrier tests this interface and encounters Error: socket hang up error, I want to know what caused this error. I have seen the current HttpServletResponse has the correct content when I debugged.
My code is blow:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class ForwardInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "RestTemplateSupportGzip")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        log.info("Start preparing forward request from {} to {}.", request.getRequestURI(), request.getRequestURL());
        // 获取原始请求的URL、请求方法、请求体和请求头
        String originalUrl = request.getRequestURI();
        String forwardUrl = getForwardUrl(originalUrl);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(forwardUrl)) {
            return true;
        }
        // 提取域名部分
        String domain = forwardUrl.replaceFirst(".*://", "").split("/")[0];

        // 原请求头和请求体都需要保留
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
            if (!HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH.equalsIgnoreCase(headerName) && !HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING.equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
                String headerValue = "Host".equalsIgnoreCase(headerName) ? domain : request.getHeader(headerName);
                headers.add(headerName, headerValue);
            }
        }
        headers.remove(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN, "https://" + domain);
        String originalBody = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

        // 原来链接上的参数页保留
        forwardUrl = forwardUrl + (StringUtils.isBlank(request.getQueryString()) ? "" : "?" + request.getQueryString());

        // 创建转发请求
        RequestEntity<String> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(originalBody, headers, HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod()), URI.create(forwardUrl));

        // 发送转发请求
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);

        // 将转发请求的响应设置到原始响应中
        response.setStatus(responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
        if (!responseEntity.getHeaders().isEmpty()) {
            responseEntity.getHeaders().forEach((key, value) -> response.setHeader(key, value.get(0)));
            response.setContentType(Objects.requireNonNull(responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType()).toString());
        }
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(Objects.requireNonNull(responseEntity.getBody()));
        // response.getWriter().close();

        log.info("Forward request from {} to {} success.", originalUrl, forwardUrl);
        // 停止后续处理
        return false;
    }

    private String getForwardUrl(String originalUrl) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(originalUrl)) {
            return null;
        }
        String prefix = originalUrl.substring(0, originalUrl.indexOf("/", 1));
        String forwardPrefix = DynamicConfigUtils.getValue("backend-forward.prefix", StringUtils.EMPTY);
        if (StringUtils.isAnyBlank(prefix, forwardPrefix) || !forwardPrefix.contains(prefix)) {
            return null;
        }
        String domain = DynamicConfigUtils.getValue(String.format("backend-forward.domain.%s", prefix.replaceAll("/", "")), StringUtils.EMPTY);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(domain)) {
            return null;
        }
        return domain + originalUrl.replace(prefix, StringUtils.EMPTY);
    }
}
```

This is nothing helpful in Google. Thanks for you help!